# UIStatusBar header : facebook messenger or tethering mode like

Tags: ios, facebook, uinavigationcontroller, user-experience, tethering

Since Facebook decided to separate the chat feature into a standalone app, this one has a blue header on top which enables the user to go back directly on facebook (using URL scheme I guess)

We can observe the same kind of UX design while using tethering or Apple Maps.

Is it something that can be implemented using iOS base SDK , or is it completely custom made ?
 and Facebook just copied the UX of the mentionned OS native apps ?

Thanks